# AWS Glue unable to overwrite file

Tags: amazon-web-services, pyspark, aws-glue

I am trying to use the mode(overwrite) when I am writing files using pyspark, please find the code below:

```
    df_export= glueContext.create_data_frame_from_options(
    connection_type="s3", format="csv", format_options={'withHeader': True},
    connection_options={"paths": [path_to_combined_file], "recurse": True})
df_concat = df_export.union(df)

df_concat = df_concat.distinct()

df_concat.repartition(1).write.format("csv").option("header", "true").mode("overwrite").save(
path_to_combined_file)
```

but I keep getting this error: An error occurred while calling o109.save. No such file or directory 's3://export/part-00000-9b670304-8c50-4d99-8a2c-f8f7f5c9a38d-c000.csv' - it has full S3 permissions

Comment: This was because I was reading and writing to the same folder, not best practise and now writing to a different folder

Comment: This looks like an error in reading the data. In your call to save function, it uses "-test" in the prefix, and the s3 path in the error doesn't contain "-test". Have you checked the data you are trying to create a df from exists in the s3 path?

Comment: thanks newbie that was not the issue but have corrected that on the question